# How to turn off title bar window numbering in KDE?

Tags: kde, kde5, kwin

When I open multiple windows with the same title (for example two file managers), every next window gets a number in it's title bar and task bar entry.

Image:

[image]

You can see that the second instance of Dolphin has a "<2>" in it's title. How to turn this off? Apparently this is a feature of `kwin`, but there is nothing about it in any `kwin` settings I found.

Comment: .......but why?

Comment: Because I then close the first Dolphin window and the second one still has the `<2>` even though it's the only one and it's annoying. Or I open an app with a splash screen which opens the main window and the main window always has the `<2>` because the splash screen (which is gone now) got to be the first window.

Comment: Your reasoning sounds valid, but I see reindexing on window open/close event as a better solution. And I don't think it's possible to change the current behavior through configuration, so you would have to file a bug if you want to have this feature eventually.

Comment: Yes it would also be a solution. If it can't be done with configuration and you have any sources on that I can accept that as an answer.